# Resource isolation and potential impact between multiple projects in Galaxybase graph database

Tags: graph-databases

We have recently decided to adopt Galaxybase as our graph database solution, and we plan to use it across multiple projects. I would like to inquire about the potential impact between different projects when using Galaxybase. Specifically, I'm interested in understanding if Galaxybase supports resource isolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galaxybase supports limiting the CPU cores and allocating memory limits for different graph databases using Docker containers. However, due to internal requirements, we currently provide a non-Docker deployment version, which means that controlling CPU and memory during runtime is not possible at the moment.

Within the same graph database, CPU and memory are not isolated among different users. Different users can have different query concurrency configurations and CPU limit settings, but this does not achieve the level of resource isolation.

Regarding storage, each graph has its own storage path, allowing us to achieve storage isolation by mounting different disk partitions.